# SPARQL query returns no data

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Why does [this SPARQL query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=%20PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FLouis%2C_Prince_of_Cond%C3%A9_(1530%E2%80%931569)%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) return [no data](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FLouis%2C_Prince_of_Cond%C3%A9_%281530%E2%80%931569%29%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)?

```
 PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT *
WHERE { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Louis,_Prince_of_Condé_(1530–1569)> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract            
}
LIMIT 1
```

If you look at [the DBpedia page](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Louis,_Prince_of_Cond%C3%A9_(1530%E2%80%931569)), it shows the person has an abstract. Is it to do with the brackets in the URL? If so, how can I get round this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This URI does not lead to the same result as the DBpedia page - for what ever reason. You can see this with

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Louis,_Prince_of_Condé_(1530–1569)> ?p ?o          
}
LIMIT 100
```

But it has an owl:sameAs relation to
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Louis,_Prince_of_Cond%C3%A9_(1530%E2%80%931569)

That means if you use this URI in your query, it should work as expected. But you should indeed apply a FILTER on the language, e.g. 'en' for English abstracts.

Comment: You don't have to use a different IRI, though.  You could use a property path to walk those owl:sameAs links to other equivalent resources, which may then have the abstract.  I posted an example as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561345/1281433).

Answer (score 3):

As AKSW mentions, the resource actually doesn't have many properties, but is connected to the "canonical" version by an owl:sameAs link.  You can keep using the IRI that you're using now, follow owl:sameAs in either direction to any of its equal resources (let's call them ?s), and then ask for the abstract of ?s.  (And then it's not a bad idea to filter by language, if that's applicable.) You can do this with a query like this (note that the current DBpedia endpoint uses **dbo:**, now, not the older **dbpedia-owl:**):

```sql
select ?abstract where {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Louis,_Prince_of_Condé_(1530–1569)> (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?s .
   ?s dbo:abstract ?abstract .

  filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en')
}
```

Comment: re: "note that the current DBpedia endpoint uses `dbo:`, now, not the older dbpedia-owl:`" -- note that while this is a default `prefix` on the endpoint, manual `prefix` setting, as seen in the OP's question, remains an option.

Comment: @TallTed Indeed, a user can define whatever prefixes they like.  That said, I generally try to post code that can be copied and pasted directly into [the endpoint web interface](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), (Of course, this means that all my *old* posts that use **dbpedia-owl:** now *don't* work...)

Comment: Of course, if you had included the `PREFIX dbpedia-owl:` declarations in your old posts (or go back and add them now), they would continue to (or will once again) work.

Comment: @TallTed Indeed.  At the moment, though, I've got [209 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1281433+[dbpedia]+is%3Aanswer) in the [tag:dbpedia] tag.  I'm not going to worry too much about going back and checking all of them.

Answer (score 2):

It does not have `dbpedia-owl:abstract` predicate. If you list its predicates you find the following properties:

```
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs
http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name
http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/alias
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthYear
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathYear
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/viafId
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathPlace
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate
```